# T-SQL ISNULL in where Condition performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for opinions and possibly a concrete answer to the following.

This question applies for SQL Server version 2008 R2+

In a stored procedure, I have an optional query parameter of type DATE, lets call it @MyVar.

The stored procedure executes the following query:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Field1 = ISNULL(@MyVar,MyTable.Field1)
```

What is the cost of doing the ISNULL(@MyVar,MyTable.Field1) if @MyVar is NULL?
I am wondering if it's better to split the cases such as:

```
IF (@MyVar IS NULL)
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM MyTable
ELSE
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar
```

Thanks!

Comment: it does prevent use of indexes, since you're comparing `field1` against a per-field calculated value, which cannot be indexed.

Comment: You mean `WHERE MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar` at the end.

Comment: @MarcB I don't see why it would prevent the use of indexes

Comment: maybe the parser's smart enough to convert OP's query into  @honeybadger's version below, but `isnull()` is a function call, and will be evaluated for every row. all else being equal, isnull's results will not be stored/calculated in advance, meaning that the query will do a full-table scan and evaluate every row.

Comment: Since this is a pattern we often see in things like searches they have come to be known by some as "catch all queries". There are some serious considerations from a performance standpoint to think about. Check out this great article from Gail Shaw on the topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @MarcB If there is an index in `Field1` there's no reason for the optimizer to just ignore it. You don't need for the results to be stored calculated in advance to use an index

Comment: You might want to read Erland Sommarskog's [post](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 11):

A more elegant approach would be:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar
   OR  @MyVar IS NULL
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

**edit**

Based on suggestion by @JamesZ, added `option(recompile)` so that an index on `field1` will be used (if it exists).

**edit2** (Thanks @Y.B. for pointing it out.)

If `field1` can be `null` as well use something like:

```
SELECT A, B, C
    FROM   MyTable
    WHERE  MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar
       OR  (@MyVar IS NULL AND MyTable.Field1 IS NULL)
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

This already shows the problems with 'catch all' queries. You could also, for example, replace the `AND` in the last query with `OR`, which would give yet another (theoretical) result set, but could potentially be correct as well.

Comment: This still doesn't use indexes, but is definitely simpler to read, although I would add parenthesis to prevent future bugs.

Comment: @JamesZ, If more conditions are added, for sure, add parentheses. I'm not sure what you are getting at about the indexes.

Comment: There's a discussion in the comments about index usage -- and if `Field1` is indexed, it will not be used even if `@MyVar` is not null, unless `option (recompile)` is used.

Comment: @JamesZ, interesting, I didn't realize that. Added to answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Technically this query output would be different to the OP's first query when `MyTable.Field1 IS NULL` and `@MyVar IS NULL`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Nope, still not exactly the same: OP's first query would never return rows where `Field1 IS NULL`. It should be `(@MyVar IS NULL AND MyTable.Field1 IS **NOT** NULL)` in yours. Sorry for nitpicking, this actually is immaterial. It's just this logic of `NULL` value handling that is always a bit counter-intuitive. Please have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Y.B. I know it's not exactly the same, that was not the intention of the edit. My intention was to show the potential problems with different `null` values and how to proces them. What the actual solution would be is up to OP.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance have 2 procedures, one that takes @MyVar and one that doesn't.  That way you get a query plan for each case not the first one you encounter (see [parameter sniffing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/)).

Have the client call whichever one makes sense depending on whether you have a value to use or not.

If you're concerned about duplicating code add a `view` for the guts of your query

```
SELECT A, B, C
    FROM MyTable
```

and select from that with conditions that make sense.
It's not magic.  There is no one size fits all unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.Field1 = ISNULL(@MyVar,MyTable.Field1)
```

would not return records where `Field1 is NULL` whereas

```
IF (@MyVar IS NULL)
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM MyTable
ELSE
    SELECT A, B, C
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar
```

would.

Technically the correct and efficient way to rewrite the original expression would be:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM MyTable
WHERE @MyVar IS NULL AND MyTable.Field1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C
FROM MyTable
WHERE @MyVar IS NOT NULL AND MyTable.Field1 = @MyVar
```